# Wysiwyg editor with php/html support (without breaking the code)

Tags: php, tinymce, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I search for wysiwyg editor with fully support of HTML and PHP.
I dont want extra p and b tags after php start tag and before close tag.
I prefer to work with PHP to get the content with $_POST.
I don't want ajax methods.

I test some editors all morning and cannot find proper.

I tested this editors:
uEditor (baidu),
htmlphpeditor,
ckeditor,
tinyMCE,
Line control
and some others...
Every of them added extra tags in php/html code. I catch the content with $_POST.
I read a lot of alternatives to strip br/p tags for ckeditor and tinymce, but without success. When i strip p - br is show and cant remove'em.

I want simple editor with php/html support and some useful bbcodes in toolbar.

Comment: Why don't you make your own https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSAQK4Nwkm4

Comment: What kind of PHP support do you need? Snippets or real, actual PHP? If it's just snippets I would definitely go with CKE and custom widgets.

Comment: Nope, I need real (actual) support. :)

Answer (score 1):

i think tinyMCE is the best wysiwyg editor for web platforms. i use it too with my php framework. You can configure this tool very nice and ofc you also can disable those tags.

```
force_p_newlines : false
```

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:force_p_newlines

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration

read docus :) they are your friend! have a nice sunny day bro ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read the documentation and I try this option in config file already.
Yes, the function stop p tags, but enable and appear br tags.
If anyone knows how to completely off br/p tags from ckeditor / tinymce - I agree on such alternative.

Comment: so try `force_br_newlines : false`, or with version 3.x `forced_root_block: '';` http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:force_br_newlines

Comment: I've used ckeditor extensively for a few years, but I've never seen it or tinymce support PHP. How exactly does this work?

Comment: @messerbill, i try - not working. (br tags still exists)

Nenotlep:
I made simple cms and this editor is needed in admin control area to added modules in the main core. (clear php/html)
I need editor which support php and html and not added extra tags like p/br

Comment: do you set the configs inside the init() method of tinymce?

Comment: if you use version 3.x delete `force_br_newlines` and `force_p_newlines`. Just use `forced_root_block: ''` in this case. otherwise (if you use tinyMCE 2.x or lower) delete the `forced_root_block: ''` and keep the other two functions.

Comment: i can not really see anything in the video, because the quality is not that good...whats the line @ 20 seconds?

Comment: The quality is bad because is fresh uploaded. Now you have option to see in 720p quality :) (Refresh the page)

Comment: hum, ok, but what is the problem? the wysiwyg editor needs a <br> or a <p> tag to do a linebreak inside the editor. How else should the editor display, "what you see" inside him? you know what i mean?

Comment: The content from editor is sended in custom made files (from cms) for me the best option is to convert br/p to \n \r (new line) In other way, br or p will be written by hand if we need them.

Comment: try `forced_root_block: '\n'`

Comment: hm, so better write your own little editor to do this. the other option would be to send the generated data (with the <br> tags) to another php function, which parses the string and replaces all `<br>` into `\n`. Maybe mySQL can do such things, but i dont know. I would do it via php, or write an own little editor for this

Comment: Ok, maybe the option with own editor is the best for now. Thank you for the replies!

Comment: no problem, but i think it would be less work to parse the string and replace the <br> tags before sending it to database :)